# Jenkins Pipeline 'Wrap' Stages for Xvfb start

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to wrap stages by using:

```
      wrap([$class: 'Xvfb', additionalOptions: '', assignedLabels: '', autoDisplayName: true, debug: true, displayNameOffset: 100, installationName: 'XVFB', parallelBuild: true]) {
```

If I have Jenkins file with below lines, how can I start the Xvfb first then start running the tests suite? In other words how to wrap the stages?

```
pipeline {

agent any 
             parameters{
             choice(choices: 'chrome\nfirefox\nie' , description: 'choose browser name' , name: 'browser')
             choice(choices: 'false\ntrue'  , description: 'Not running on Selenium Grid?' , name: 'localRun')
        }

stages {
      stage('Install Parent Project') {
        steps {
        sh 'mvn -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ clean install -DskipTests=true'
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI: most browsers now support native headless mode, so there is no more need for xvfb.

Comment: @SiKing really? I get a "cannot find Chrome binary" error

Comment: You need to add headless ChromeOption, cannot find binary I think it's because you didn't add chrome driver as a system variable in your code.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to add the wrap block with timeout:

```
    stage('Run Tests Suite') {
        steps {
         timeout(45) {
         wrap([$class: 'Xvfb', additionalOptions: '', assignedLabels: '', autoDisplayName: true, debug: true, displayNameOffset: 0, installationName: 'XVFB', parallelBuild: true, screen: '1024x758x24', timeout: 25]) {
        sh 'mvn  -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/... test -DlocalRun=${localRun} -Dbrowser=${browser} -DxmlPath='''
        }
        }
    }      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the first stage inside the wrap

```
stages {
    wrap([$class: 'Xvfb', ....) {
        stage('Install Parent Project') {
            steps {
            sh 'mvn -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ clean install -DskipTests=true'
            }
        }
    }
}
```